# Installing spacy fails with "command 'gcc-11' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: spacy

I'm trying to build an environment for a tool that requires spacy 1.9.0 with below commands

```
python3 -m venv errant_env
source errant_env/bin/activate
pip3 install -U pip wheel
pip3 install -U spacy==1.9.0
python3 -m spacy download en
```

and getting the following messages. How can I solve this?

```
Collecting spacy==1.9.0
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/ce/afee53c365617e5f3e58825d71421bce14949a15f7150742d2a7b8859c53/spacy-1.9.0.tar.gz
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.7 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: murmurhash<0.27,>=0.26 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: cymem<1.32,>=1.30 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: preshed<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Collecting thinc<6.6.0,>=6.5.0 (from spacy==1.9.0)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/9b/78fab962e0c8b55e3a745ebf2458708dfc7922c55eca3a9bff0233b25294/thinc-6.5.2.tar.gz
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: pip<10.0.0,>=9.0.0 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: six in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: pathlib in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: ujson>=1.35 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: dill<0.3,>=0.2 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy==1.9.0)
Collecting regex<2017.12.1,>=2017.4.1 (from spacy==1.9.0)
Collecting ftfy<5.0.0,>=4.4.2 (from spacy==1.9.0)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: wrapt in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc<6.6.0,>=6.5.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc<6.6.0,>=6.5.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Collecting cytoolz<0.9,>=0.8 (from thinc<6.6.0,>=6.5.0->spacy==1.9.0)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/e6/ccc124714dcc1bd511e64ddafb4d5d20ada2533b92e3173a4cf09e0d0831/cytoolz-0.8.2.tar.gz
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: termcolor in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc<6.6.0,>=6.5.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: html5lib in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ftfy<5.0.0,>=4.4.2->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: wcwidth in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ftfy<5.0.0,>=4.4.2->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: toolz>=0.8.0 in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cytoolz<0.9,>=0.8->thinc<6.6.0,>=6.5.0->spacy==1.9.0)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Requirement already up-to-date: webencodings in ./errant_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from html5lib->ftfy<5.0.0,>=4.4.2->spacy==1.9.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: spacy, thinc, cytoolz
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /project/cl-work2/yusuke/projects/context_aware_gec/errant_env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-8i5m5103/spacy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpruswh00zpip-wheel- --python-tag cp38:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  copying spacy/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  copying spacy/lemmatizer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  copying spacy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  copying spacy/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  copying spacy/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  ...
  copying spacy/tokens/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/tokens
  copying spacy/tokens/token.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/tokens
  copying spacy/tokens/doc.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/tokens
  copying spacy/tokens/span.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/tokens
  copying spacy/tests/tokenizer/sun.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/tests/tokenizer
  running build_ext
  building 'spacy.parts_of_speech' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy
  gcc-11 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/opt/zlib -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/include -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/opt/zlib -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/include -fPIC -I/home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8 -I/tmp/pip-build-8i5m5103/spacy/include -I/project/cl-work2/yusuke/projects/context_aware_gec/errant_env/include -I/home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8 -c spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/parts_of_speech.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function -fopenmp
  cc1plus: warning: command-line option '-Wno-strict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  c++ -pthread -shared -L/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/opt/readline/lib -L/home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib -L/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/lib -L/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/opt/readline/lib -L/home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib -L/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/parts_of_speech.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/parts_of_speech.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -fopenmp
  building 'spacy.strings' extension
  gcc-11 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/opt/zlib -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/include -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/opt/zlib -I/home/is/yusuke/.linuxbrew/include -fPIC -I/home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8 -I/tmp/pip-build-8i5m5103/spacy/include -I/project/cl-work2/yusuke/projects/context_aware_gec/errant_env/include -I/home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8 -c spacy/strings.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/spacy/strings.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function -fopenmp
  cc1plus: warning: command-line option '-Wno-strict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  spacy/strings.cpp: In function 'PyObject* PyInit_strings()':
  spacy/strings.cpp:5025:42: warning: '_typeobject::tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   5025 |   __pyx_type_5spacy_7strings_StringStore.tp_print = 0;
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from spacy/strings.cpp:4:
  /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
    260 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        |                              ^~~~~~~~
  spacy/strings.cpp:5025:42: warning: '_typeobject::tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   5025 |   __pyx_type_5spacy_7strings_StringStore.tp_print = 0;
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from spacy/strings.cpp:4:
  /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
    260 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        |                              ^~~~~~~~
  spacy/strings.cpp:5025:42: warning: '_typeobject::tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   5025 |   __pyx_type_5spacy_7strings_StringStore.tp_print = 0;
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from spacy/strings.cpp:4:
  /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
    260 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        |                              ^~~~~~~~
  spacy/strings.cpp:5080:59: warning: '_typeobject::tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   5080 |   __pyx_type_5spacy_7strings___pyx_scope_struct____iter__.tp_print = 0;
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from spacy/strings.cpp:4:
  /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
    260 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        |                              ^~~~~~~~
  spacy/strings.cpp:5080:59: warning: '_typeobject::tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   5080 |   __pyx_type_5spacy_7strings___pyx_scope_struct____iter__.tp_print = 0;
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from spacy/strings.cpp:4:
  /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
    260 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        |                              ^~~~~~~~
  spacy/strings.cpp:5080:59: warning: '_typeobject::tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   5080 |   __pyx_type_5spacy_7strings___pyx_scope_struct____iter__.tp_print = 0;
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from spacy/strings.cpp:4:
  /home/is/yusuke/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
    260 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        |                              ^~~~~~~~
  spacy/strings.cpp: In function 'void __Pyx_ExceptionSwap(PyObject**, PyObject**, PyObject**)':
  spacy/strings.cpp:7228:24: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'exc_type'; did you mean 'curexc_type'?
   7228 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                        ^~~~~~~~
        |                        curexc_type
  spacy/strings.cpp:7229:25: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'exc_value'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
   7229 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                         ^~~~~~~~~
        |                         curexc_value
  spacy/strings.cpp:7230:22: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'exc_traceback'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
   7230 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_traceback
  spacy/strings.cpp:7231:13: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'exc_type'; did you mean 'curexc_type'?
   7231 |     tstate->exc_type = *type;
        |             ^~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_type
  spacy/strings.cpp:7232:13: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'exc_value'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
   7232 |     tstate->exc_value = *value;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_value
  spacy/strings.cpp:7233:13: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'exc_traceback'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
   7233 |     tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_traceback
  error: command 'gcc-11' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for spacy
  Running setup.py clean for spacy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thinc: started
```

Because I found some advice recommending to do so, I installed with linuxbrew libxml2 and libxslt. But this didn't change the situation.

Also, I confirmed that gcc-11 exists at `$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-11` with `which gcc-11`.

My environments are:

- Ubuntu 18.04.6
- Python 3.8.13

Comment: I would suggest using the latest python version that was supported for this release, which was python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks. When I created a new environment of python 3.6 and ran the same command in it, I was able to install spacy.